# Join 2 tables with a column with same values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 queries i want to join them.

The first one is like this:

```
    select componentes_process.id_comp_process,componentes_process.id_intervencao,componentes_process.id_equip, componentes_equip.nome, sum(componentes_process.quantidade) as quantidade from manutencao.componentes_equip 
left join manutencao.componentes_process on componentes_process.nome=componentes_equip.nome and componentes_process.id_intervencao=1362 
where id_tipo_equip=1 group by nome order by nome asc;

+---------------+-------------------------+-------+
| id_tipo_equip |         nome          | total |
+---------------+-------------------------+-------+
| 1            | Cabo de comando        |    12 |
| 1            | Casquilhos de roda     |     3 |
| 1            | Contactos de contactor |     3 |
| 1             | Display de código     |     4 |
| 1             | Escovas de motor      |     5 |
+---------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

The second one looks like this:

```
select id_tipo_equip,componentes_equip.nome,sum(componentes_process.quantidade) as total from manutencao.componentes_equip 
left join manutencao.componentes_process on componentes_process.nome=componentes_equip.nome
left join manutencao.intervencao_process on intervencao_process.id_intervencao=componentes_process.id_intervencao
left join manutencao.processos on processos.id_process=intervencao_process.id_process and intervencao_process.id_process=639
where id_tipo_equip='1' group by nome order by nome asc;


+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------------+------------+
| id_comp_process | id_intervencao | id_equip |         nome         | quantidade |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------------+------------+
| 1151            | 1362          | 10       | Cabo de comando       | 1          |
| 1152            | 1362           | 10      | Casquilhos de roda    | 1          |
| NULL           | NULL           | NULL     | Contactos de contactor | NULL      |
| NULL            | NULL          | NULL     | Display de código      | NULL      |
| NULL            | NULL           | NULL     | Escovas de motor      | NULL      |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------------+------------+
```

I've tried this way, but with no success:

```
select componentes_process.id_comp_process,componentes_process.id_intervencao,componentes_process.id_equip, componentes_equip.nome, componentes_process.quantidade,sum(componentes_process.quantidade) as total from manutencao.componentes_equip 
    left join manutencao.componentes_process on componentes_process.nome=componentes_equip.nome and componentes_process.id_intervencao=1362
    left join manutencao.intervencao_process on intervencao_process.id_intervencao=componentes_process.id_intervencao
    left join manutencao.processos on processos.id_process=intervencao_process.id_process and intervencao_process.id_process=639
where id_tipo_equip='1' group by componentes_equip.nome ORDER BY componentes_equip.nome;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use each query as a derived table and join them:

```
SELECT ta.*, tb.* FROM

(select componentes_process.id_comp_process,componentes_process.id_intervencao,componentes_process.id_equip, componentes_equip.nome, sum(componentes_process.quantidade) as quantidade from manutencao.componentes_equip 
left join manutencao.componentes_process on componentes_process.nome=componentes_equip.nome and componentes_process.id_intervencao=1362 
where id_tipo_equip=1 group by nome) ta

INNER JOIN 

(select id_tipo_equip,componentes_equip.nome,sum(componentes_process.quantidade) as total from manutencao.componentes_equip 
left join manutencao.componentes_process on componentes_process.nome=componentes_equip.nome
left join manutencao.intervencao_process on intervencao_process.id_intervencao=componentes_process.id_intervencao
left join manutencao.processos on processos.id_process=intervencao_process.id_process and intervencao_process.id_process=639
where id_tipo_equip='1' group by nome) tb on ta.nome=tb.nome
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my response as the correct answer if this is, indeed, correct. ;)